# Cannot grab TD data below the TH data with Xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium

For the life of me I do not understand why I cannot grab the td text below the th.

I have tried this **('//th(contains(text(), "Text I Need Is After This")]')** which does grab the actual line that it's intended to grab, but what I'm trying to grab is the text in the td/a links below that.

appending **('//th(contains(text(), "Text I Need Is After This")]/td/a')** or just 
**('//th(contains(text(), "Text I Need Is After This")]/td')** does not find any matches.

Here is the HTML

```
    <tr class="">
    <th scope="row" style="text-align:left;">Text I Need Is After This</th>
    <td class="" style="">
    <a href="/wiki/Queens" title="Queens">Queens</a>, 
    <a href="/wiki/New_York" title="New York">New York</a>, 
    <a href="/wiki/United_States" title="United States">United States</a>
    </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: You have a '(' in place of a '[' in the first line

Comment: the <a> nodes are not children of the <th>, they are children of the <td>, which is a sibling to <th>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `/td/a` to the first statement is telling the XPath to find the child nodes of `<th>`, which they are not. So if you want to find the `<th>` node, and the `<td>` and `<a>` directly after, use the `following-sibling` function, like so:

```
//th[contains(text(), "Text I Need Is After This")]/following-sibling::td
```

Comment: He would need the `preceding-sibling` to test for the `th`.

Comment: You guy's are all right including the mention of the typo, I will accept the answer in 9 minutes (stack overflow will not allow it yet)

Comment: Also the path i used to get the td text is, ('//th[contains(text(), "Origin"]/following::td[1]') which grabbed all three of the a element text I needed within the td below the th, thank everybody, I love this website.

Comment: forgot to add the xpath, updated. Also, @kmkaplan's answer is good too, so whichever way that makes more sense for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using something like:

```
td[contains(preceding-sibling::text(), "Text I Need Is After This")]
```

Comment: I stand corrected sir. For some reason wasn't thinking too well, my apologies.